# How to improve MySQL query and IF statement

Tags: mysql

I came up with the following and it works as expected.

```
SET @ustotal := 0;
SET @minutostotal := 0;
SET @linea := 0;
SELECT @linea := @linea + 1 AS 'No.', 
       calldate, 
       src, 
       dst, 
       billsec, 
       @minutos := ceil(billsec/60) AS minutos, 
       IF((dst LIKE '044%' OR dst LIKE '045%'),'Celular','Local') AS Tipo,
       IF((dst LIKE '044%' OR dst LIKE '045%'), @dolares := @minutos*.048, @dolares := @minutos*.01) AS Dolares, 
       @ustotal := @ustotal + @dolares AS 'Total Dolares', 
       @minutostotal := @minutostotal + @minutos AS 'Total Minutos' 
FROM cdr 
WHERE calldate LIKE '2015-11%' 
  AND dstchannel LIKE '%aximf%' 
  and billsec>1 
  and disposition="ANSWERED";
```

For the purpose of learning, I would like to know how to improve the query. The first `IF` returns `'Celular'` or `'Local'` and it is ok but then I need to make the same `IF` again to make a calculation. On the first `IF` I would like to send the Text and also something like: `@value:=.048` (or .01 if false) so then I have only one calculation on: `@dolares:=@minutos*@value`.

All this is on MySQL 5.0.95, Centos 5.

Comment: Do not use MySQL 5.0, thats too old for any learning or anything. Other than that the effect of evaluating the same IF twice is negligible - execution time of most queries is totally dominated by the needed IO. I have an example - 3 millions of records - computing md5() on one column of all of them took  2.5s, not doing md5() but still accessing all of them (appending an empty string iirc) took 1.9s - md5() is quite fast among hash functions but still should be many times more complex than the IFs you use.

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply. My question was more about optimizing the code and not so the speed of the query. It should be a way to do only 1 IF but I cant figure how. Regards,AL

Comment: I see.. Well, SQL is not a procedural language but there are some tricks - check my answer.

Comment: The main issue I see with the query is that it is using mysql variables to calculate running totals but it doesn't have an `ORDER BY`. You may get some unpredictable results that way.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not a procedural language. There are different vendor extensions which would allow it in a stored procedure/function, but select query is a bit more limited.

That `IF` has to return exactly one expression value, so you would have to define some expression with a side effect - maybe something along

```
IF(
    (dst LIKE '044%' OR dst LIKE '045%'),
    IF(@dolares := @minutos*.048, 'Celular', 'Celular'),
    IF(@dolares := @minutos*.01, 'Local', 'Local')
)
```

I tested a simplified version and it seems to work - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/30118 - but it is not pretty and there is other duplication in the form of the returned values because I do not recall a function of the type "evaluate first parameter, forget it and return the second" for MySQL but maybe someone else can suggest one.

Answer (score 0):

The "common subexpression elimination" you are trying to do is probably *more* costly than the extra columns and assignment statements that it incurs!  A better metric may be to count the number of tokens in a statement `@x := y / 123 ,` is 6 tokens; then 2 uses of @x is 2 more tokens; total 8.  Using `y/123` twice would be only 6 tokens -- simpler and possibly faster.